# Attempting to load in data and return a GeoDataFrame, getting error

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

For a challenge, I'm trying to write a function that takes the file name of a shape file and the file name of a CSV as parameters. I want it to merge the two files at columns named `CTIDFP00` and `CensusTract` (respectively).

I want the function to return a GeoDataFrame.
This is currently what I have for the program:

`def loading_data(shapefile, csvfile): merged = shapefile.merge(csvfile, left_on='CTIDFP00', right_on='CensusTract') print(load_in_data('filepath','otherfilepath'))`

But it's returning the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'merge'`

How can I fix this in this context? I've been trying to figure it out for nearly two hours now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the dataframes before you merge them.

```py
def loading_data(shapefile, csvfile):
df1 = #load the shapefile
df2 = #load the csvfile 
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='CTIDFP00', right_on='CensusTract') 

print(load_in_data('filepath','otherfilepath'))
```